# Clustering in "WEBGL JAVASCRIPT MAPS" React

Tags: trimble-maps

I am looking to cluster Points or GeoJSON in Trimble Maps (ReactJS). There's an example in the JS version but don't see it in WEBGL JAVASCRIPT MAPS.

Does someone have any example to use?

reference: https://developer.trimblemaps.com/trimble-maps/2.0/api/#marker

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

We just this week added some new examples to our WebGL documentation, including one related to clustering. https://developer.trimblemaps.com/trimble-maps/2.0/examples/cluster-points/

I hope it is helpful.